# How to replace an array in .cpp file to equal a .json file?

Tags: c++, arrays, json

I need to replace a variable, `foobarType`, that is assigned an array within the code with an arrayfrom a `.json` file, `table.json`.

In the original `.cpp` file:

```cpp
typedef struct{
 int foo;
 int bar;
} foobarType;

static foobarType table[foobars_in_table] = {
{ 123, 456 },
{ 789, 101 }
};

//code
...
```

I need to replace the array in the `.cpp` file with a `.json` file, "table.json":
**EDIT**: I change the array in the file into a valid json format.

```
[
{"foo":"111","bar":"222"},
{"foo":"33","bar":"444"}

]
```

I've tried changing the `.cpp` file with:

```cpp
#include<fstream>

std::ifstream jsonTable("table.json", std::ifstream::binary);
// tried: std::ifstream jsonTable("table.json", std::fstream::binary);

typedef struct{
 int foo;
 int bar;
} foobarType;

static foobarType table[foobars_in_table] = jsonTable;
// tried: static foobarType table[foobars_in_table] = jsonTable[];

//code
…
```

but I get an error:
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::ifstream' to foobarType [142]'

Comment: You cannot simply "assign" a JSON to a C++ array, the compiler has no way of knowing what the file contains beforehand. You need to actually parse the file

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, is that intended?

Comment: Do you need to read/process `json` data or only to produce it? For simple cases, making a producer is easy, otherwise, get yourself a `json` library capable of dealing with all the stuff that's in the `json` standard.

Comment: You need to use a json parser like this one at https://github.com/nlohmann/json. Also it looks like the json is not valid json either as [] are used for arays and {} are used for objects.

Comment: @yksisarvinen I need my array too look like that, but I could change it to be valid and parse it as UnholySheep suggests. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Scotty Since you do the `typedef struct` thingy, are you expecting this to be C compatible in the end?

Comment: Are you trying to write C++ code to parse JSON? If not, why are you putting JSON in there instead of valid C++ code?

Comment: @TedLygmo yes. Original dev bailed with the README.md, and I can't npm my way out of it.

Comment: But you have a C++ compiler? If you do `struct foobarType {
 int foo;
 int bar;
};` you should have your custom class `foobarType` ready for use without that `typedef`. It's built-in the language.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Long story short, this part of the app is written in C++ to generate a file for devices that are running C. I just want to serve it a file instead of editing a table in the source file. Can't tell you how and why they did it this way? Lets assume it written in C++. What can this JS dev do to make this work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz changed the array to valid json format.

Comment: @Scotty Easiest way forward: 1) Pick a `json` lib. Something `Modern` or `rapid` will probably pop up if you search for it. 2) Just put the raw `json` data in a `json` string from the chosen lib and you're good to go.