# Assign array from an array in text file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

How do I assign an array from a text file to an array as a variable?

data.txt

```
{
{ 123, 456 },
{ 789, 101 }
}
```

program.cpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PgnFileCreator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::ifstream dataArray("assets/data.txt", std::fstream::binary);

typedef struct {
   int foo;
   int bar;
} dataArrayType;


static dataArrayType dataTable[IPSUM] = dataArray;

//code
```

Error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::ifstream' to dataArrayType[142]'
```

Context
The code is executed in "Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.5.1" and asked not to change it.

Comment: For something that sounds an awfully lot like a homework assignment, you have yet to show anything that you've tried. Looks to me that you were handed a template by your professor and now you're coming here for us to solve your homework for you.

Comment: Also, coming here and trying to spam the same question multiple time is a great way to get your account permanently removed, I'm sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108987/how-to-replace-an-array-in-cpp-file-to-equal-a-json-file

Comment: @searchengine27: To be fair, that question is related, but not identical.

Comment: @searchengine27 not at all. I primarily dev with NPM and I'm tasked to automate c++ which I barely know anything about for a friend.

Comment: please don't assume. I genuinely need help. I changed the parameters.

Comment: Again, what have you tried? Doesn't seem to me that you've tried anything. This is a helping community -not a do it for you community. People won't be bothered to help if you don't have an eagerness to help yourself. And that other question is the same question. You may not realize it, but if you googled some things about what you asked, you might discover that it is.

Comment: I've tried using libraries (like in my NPM workflow, like moderate JSON, but I run into compatibility errors. I'm asking if there is an efficient way, that I am not cued on, or just write a parsing function with a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When reading a line of text, the `std::getline` should be use:

```
std::string  text_line;
std::getline(data_file, text_line);
```

Looks like your input file is line oriented, so you'll have to use `std::getline` pattern a lot.

There is nothing in your presented input data that tells the number of records in advance, so I recommend using `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` will grow on demand, as long as you use the `push_back` method.

From my experience, parsing simple text from a string is easiest performed using `std::istringstream`:

```
char open_brace;
char comma;
int foo = 0;
int bar = 0;
const std::string test_data = "{ 123, 456}";
std::istringstream test_stream(test_data);
test_stream >> open_brace
            >> foo
            >> comma
            >> bar;
```

With the above fundamentals, you should be able to figure out how to read in the matrix.
Ideally, it should look like:

```
struct dataType // the "typedef" is not required in C++
{
    int foo, bar;
};
//...
std::vector<dataType> database;
dataType d;
while (data_file >> d)
{
    database.push_back(d);
}
```

Hint: search your favorite C++ for operator overloading.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What do you recommend the best way to structure the data in a file if the file contain int, string, and Booleans?

Comment: One record per line.  Use a delimiter between fields, like spaces or commas.  You may want review XML or JSON file formats.